# Runnable callbacks not repeating

Tags: java, android

I want to remove previous callback, the problem is that the mRunnable call only calls once, it doesn't repeat what I am doing?

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Test ....");

        }
};

@Override
    public void onJoystickContinue(Boolean isContinue) {
        if (isContinue == true) {
            if (mHandler != null) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            }
            mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500);
        } else {
            if (mHandler != null) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a new runnable instance each time instead of reusing the same instance over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `mRunnable` is created once when the enclosing class is created. The `Runnable` instance runs and transitions to the "stopped" state. So when you reuse it later, the handler attempts to run it, but it is already stopped. One solution here is to create a new runnable instance each time you restart instead of reusing the same instance over and over.

Comment: @thomas Do you know how to create a new object and assign it to a variable?

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing in the first line.

Comment: @thomas It is. The issue here is that line only executes once when you create an object of the containing class. You need to rearrange your code so that it happens each time you post to the handler.